# Why do I get the error 'IBMQManagedResultDataNotAvailable'?

Tags: programming, qiskit, qasm

I'm trying to use IBMQ job manager to submit a list of quantum circuits (300 of them in total) to 'ibmq_16_melbourne'. This is what the job status looks like on IBM Quantum Experience: [image]

I don't know why my code doesn't work on this real quantum computer. If I use the ibmq_qasm_simulator instead then no error has occurred. Here's the structure of my code:

```
from qiskit import IBMQ
IBMQ.load_account()
provider = IBMQ.get_provider()
backend = provider.get_backend('ibmq_16_melbourne')
job_manager = IBMQJobManager()

all_circuits = [...]    # A list with 300 elements.
MyExperiments = job_manager.run(all_circuits, backend=backend, shots = 100)
results = MyExperiments.results()
```

I tried another list with 5 simple circuits and it worked fine, but I'm wondering how can I make  it work in my case with 300 circuits? What should I do? Thanks a lot for your help:)

Comment: It seems like you tried to do some additional operation with the quantum circuit after measurement is being executed, yes? If that is the case then that might be the issue.

Comment: @KAJ226 Thanks for the comment! Could you explain a bit more about the 'additional operation'? I checked out the error message page and it looks like that's the case, but I don't think I have any gates added after the measurement.

Comment: Can you post the circuits you are executing or the code to generate the circuits you are looking at?

Comment: What I mean by additional operation after measurement is if you tried to apply some quantum gates after applying the measurement operator... This is because IBM hardware is not yet supporting mid-circuit measurement (at least on the public available devices). So says, you apply a Hadamard gate, make a measurement, then apply another hadamard gate after the measurement. This will give you an error.